# FlatList not Rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am trying to use FlatList but FlatList is not working.
-Android

This work

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

this is not working

```
 <FlatList       
     data={this.state.dataSource}
     keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}   
     renderItem={({ item}) =>{console.log(item);}}
    >
```

Comment: What do you mean it's not working? like there's no log statements in your debugger?

Comment: My debugger does not write anything.

Comment: Can you copy-paste `this.state.dataSource` as well as `this._keyExtractor` here too? I did the same thing but mine logs the items with no problem, so I guess it's because something's wrong with those two

Comment: There is no problem when I use ListView but I am using FlatList and it does not write data.

Comment: I cannot answer your question if you don't copy-paste your code here, I am doing the same thing but my debugger shows the objects I'm logging perfectly, there are many reasons this would happen, without your code, it's almost impossible to identify any sort of problem. For all I know, `this.state.dataSource` could be an empty array

Comment: you are right, my friend. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, it's inside your `componentWillMount`:

```
componentWillMount() {
    return fetch('...')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((responseJson) => {
            let ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });
            this.setState({
                isLoading: false,
                dataSource: ***ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson).rowIdentities***
            });
        });
}
```

I did `console.log(ds.cloneWithRows(responseJson))` like what you did initially but got things like this:

[image]

The data that we care about are in `rowIdentities`

Comment: Isn't `rowIdentities` meant for ListView? How is it related to Flatlist?